# Preload Android Recyclerview items with StaggeredGridLayoutManager

Tags: android, performance, android-recyclerview

**Problem:** How to preload recyclerview items to give best user experience to users.

Found this [**blog**](https://androiddevx.wordpress.com/2014/12/05/recycler-view-pre-cache-views/) doing the same thing but its doing with `LinearLayoutManager` not with `StaggeredGridLayoutManager`.

Methods `setExtraLayoutSpace` and `setInitialPrefetchItemCount(int)` is not avalabile in  `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` API.

How i can load some `items(images)` before user scroll to give better user experience.

Comment: Do you get any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

> Its not the perfect way but still it works.
>
> Create intent service for loading/cache images in background when user
> scroll to load new post it will fetch it from cache instead of going
> to server.

**ImageCahce.java**

```
public class ImageCache extends IntentService {

    Context mContext;

    public ImageCache() {
        super("ImageCache");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mContext = this;
        Log.d("ImageCache", "Service Started");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (intent != null)
            if (intent.getStringExtra(Constants.IncomingClass) != null)
                if (intent.getStringExtra(Constants.IncomingClass).equalsIgnoreCase("Trending")) {
                    ArrayList<Trending> items = intent.getExtras().getParcelableArrayList(Constants.CacheKey);
                    StartCachingImages(items);
                }
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    //Trending logic
    private void StartCachingImages(final ArrayList<Trending> items) {

        if (items != null) {
            if (!items.isEmpty()) {
                for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {

                    Post pogo = items.get(i).postObj;
                    String imagePath = "";
                    if (pogo.type.equalsIgnoreCase("Picture")) {
                        imagePath = pogo.picture;
                    } else if (pogo.type.equalsIgnoreCase("Video")) {
                        imagePath = pogo.thumbnail;
                    } else if (pogo.type.equalsIgnoreCase("Multimedia")) {
                        //  imagePath = pogo.thumbnail;
                        if (pogo.picture.length() > 0) imagePath = pogo.picture;
                        else imagePath = pogo.thumbnail;
                    }

                    //Log.d("ImageCache", "index " + i + " started");
                    BackgroundCaching backgroundCaching = new BackgroundCaching(i, imagePath, items.get(i).userObj.picture);
                    backgroundCaching.execute();
                }
                //Log.d("ImageCache", "Self stopping");
                ImageCache.this.stopSelf();
            }
        }
    }

    class BackgroundCaching extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        String path, thumbnail;
        int id;

        public BackgroundCaching(int id, String path, String thumbnail) {
            this.id = id;
            this.path = path;
            this.thumbnail = thumbnail;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                FutureTarget<File> future = Glide.with(mContext).load(path)
                        .downloadOnly(Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL, Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL);
                future.get();
                //Log.d("ImageCache", "Loaded actual " + id);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //Log.d("ImageCache", "Failed to load ->" + path);
            }
            try {
                FutureTarget<File> future = Glide.with(mContext).load(thumbnail)
                        .downloadOnly(Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL, Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL);
                future.get();

                //Log.d("ImageCache", "Loaded thumbnail " + id);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //Log.d("ImageCache", "Failed to load ->" + thumbnail);
            }
            return "Executed";
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d("ImageCache", "Service Stopped");
    }
}
```

use `StartImageCacheService()` to start service.

```
 void StartImageCacheService(Context context, LinkedList<com.fayvo.Model.Trending> trendingHash) {
        if (context != null && trendingHash.size() > 0) {
            Intent i = new Intent(context, ImageCache.class);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            i.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Constants.CacheKey, new ArrayList<com.fayvo.Model.Trending>(trendingHash));
            i.putExtra(Constants.IncomingClass, "Trending");
            context.startService(i);
        }
    }
```

To give better user experience i have